# Pseudo element is not scrollable when it has a transparent background

Tags: css, scroll, frontend, overflow, pseudo-element

I have some text displaying in an `::after` psuedo element that I would like to be scrollable. It works fine until I change the background of that element from:

`background-color: rgb(0,0,0);`

to:

`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Is there a way to allow scrolling with a transparent background?

---

Here is the HTML with working and broken example:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="column working">
    <p>Working: text is scrolling properly.</p><br>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x200" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column broken">
    <p>Broken: text is not scrolling.</p><br>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x200" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS to go with it:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: monaco;
}

.container::after {
  content: "Dis iusto aliquid sollicitudin iaculis modi fugit, non irure quisquam molestiae arius laboris, eiusmod? Pulvinar eleifend volutpat, quae nunc magnam? Hac, nam? Dignissimos esse diamlorem dolore accusamus dolores, ipsa facilis ullam illo, fames ex? Maecenas tellus. Aspernatur eum malesuada, assumenda, hac, ultricies? Aliquet in, harum fugiat! Volutpat recusandae! Fames saepe fames corrupti.";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: monaco;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: aqua;
}

.column.working .container::after {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.column.broken .container::after {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

img {
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-family: monaco;
}
```

And here is the above code, in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/roaYvX)

Thanks.

Comment: both scroll for me in the codepen. Is there a particular browser you're having an issue with? I suggest clearing your browser cache and/or restarting your computer and re-running your code..

Comment: both working...

Comment: It's likely a bug in the browser or scrollable content is not meant to be used in `:after` or `:before`. It's works fine in FireFox but in Chrome only the first one works, in MS Edge neither of them work not even dragging the scrollbars or using mouse-wheel. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out either.

Comment: @StudioKonKon both are fine in Chrome for me

Comment: I'm not sure about Chris, but I'm using the latest version "Chrome Version 71.0.3578.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)" same with IE, Opera and FireFox latest on Windows 10. Even your answer doesn't work for me. I noticed a slight delay rendering the `:after` content

Comment: Thanks all. Similar to many comments, both examples in my CodePen work for me in Firefox but neither work in Safari.

I was mostly testing in Chrome (Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)) where, oddly, the "broken" example works sometimes (after reloading the page or the browser) and sometimes not!

So I'm chalking this up to a browser bug and will adjust the layout to never necessitate scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, this appears to be a browser bug that has since been fixed. Marking as resolved.